# Is postfix self assignment behaviour strictly defined in C#/Java?

Tags: java, c#, c++, postfix-operator

I understand that the following code is known to produce undefined behavior in C/C++

```
   int i = 1;
   i = 2*i++;
   cout << i << endl; // surprisingly 3, undefined...
```

It produces the expected result of 2 in Java/C#. But is this a guarantee in Java/C# or still undefined behavior?

Comment: Why the null edit? Is this a common thing now?

Comment: Well, he removed the [c++] tag, later realized he was wrong and reverted it.

Comment: Even if the result was well defined, why would you want to write code like that?

Comment: You probably wouldn't directly, but it could happen through references being sent to functions as parameters

Answer (score 1):

In C# this is very well defined.

1. It increments the variable.
2. It assigns the old value to the variable

So the value of the variable remains unchanged. The result will be 2 with your case here.

```
 i = i++
```

This is same as

```
   t = i
   i = i + 1
   i = t
```

This kind of expression will get very confusing when it comes as a part of compound statement. It would be very advisable to keep expressions simple and less confusing for yourself and others in the long run.

The expressions are evaluated from left to right in both Java and C#

Comment: Thanks. But this is how I expected it to work in C++ as well.  Any link to specific documentation on the validity of post-fix self-assignment in C#?

Comment: `=` has lower precedence in c#. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/language-reference/operators/increment-operator says `The second form is a postfix increment operation. The result of the operation is the value of the operand before it has been incremented.`

Comment: Thanks for your response. I appreciate the effort. FYI, again , the same is true for C++. But then it becomes undefined because of sequencing rules, which I wondered if only apply for C++